# shutil copy error

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a file named test_target.sh(target is a variable here) to ROOT which is the destination location,am running into compilation error while trying to make the name test_target.sh ..any input on how to fix it?

import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call,Popen, PIPE
from shutil import copyfile

```
def main ():
    ROOT = '/local/mnt/workspace'
    target = 'msm8960'
    copyfile("./test_" + target + ".sh", ROOT + "./test_" + target + ".sh")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/local/mnt/workspace./test_msm8960.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to include the `./`, the `_` and the `.sh` in the string:

```
copyfile("./test_" + target + ".sh", ROOT)
```

Just like that, you have to make those other values strings too, or they should fail as well:

```
ROOT = '/local/mnt/workspace'
target = 'wsc1234'
```

Also, as ernie correctly noticed in the comments, `copyfile` does not exist in your code. If you want to use it just like that, you need to import the function directly using

```
from shutil import copyfile
```

otherwise you need to use `shutil.copyfile(...)` instead.

#### Edit

> No such file or directory: '/local/mnt/workspace./test_msm8960.sh

The folder `workspace.` does not exist. You should use `ROOT + "/test_" + target + ".sh"` for the target filename (note the missing dot).

Comment: I'm curious why it didn't error on the assignments of `ROOT` and `target`, which appear to use bare strings?

Comment: @ernie Oh, I see now what you mean; didn’t even notice that. I suspect that OP showed a different file version than he run (givent hat the error is different as well).

Comment: Also, that'll need to be `shutil.copyfile` won't it?

Comment: @ernie Yes, that too, thanks! Maybe you should have posted your own answer xD

Comment: @poke - If I do that,I am getting an error IIOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/local/mnt/workspace./test_msm8960.sh

Comment: @user1927396 `copyfile` expects the target to be a filename; if you want to copy a file into a directory, use `shutil.copy` instead.